# How to delete a file after uploading using Struts 2?

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload, struts2, nio2

I am able to upload a file using Struts2, but I want to drop the specified directory
but I don't know how to delete a file.

**Here is  my code:**

```
public String execute(){
  destPath = "/tmp/listfile";
  try{
    System.out.println("Src File name: " + myFile);
    System.out.println("Dst File name: " + myFileFileName);                 
    File destFile  = new File(destPath, myFileFileName);
    FileUtils.copyFile(myFile, destFile);
    fileList = ListFiles.ListAllFiles("/tmp/listfile");  
    return "listfiles";  
  }
  catch(IOException e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return "ERROR";
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to delete `myFile` ?

Comment: yes,after uploading i want to delete....

Answer (score 1):

If you use Apache Commons IO it's a one-liner:

```
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(dir);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to move file instead of copy

```
public String execute() {
  String destPath = "/tmp/listfile";
  try {
    System.out.println("Src File name: " + myFile);
    System.out.println("Dst File name: " + myFileFileName);                 
    Path source = Paths.get(myFile.getAbsolutePath());
    Path target = Paths.get(destPath);
    Files.move(source, target.resolve(myFileFileName), REPLACE_EXISTING);
    fileList =ListFiles.ListAllFiles("/tmp/listfile");  
    return "listfiles";  
   } catch(IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     return "ERROR";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FileUtils.getFile(destFile).delete();
```